# Consequence of elliptic estimates up to the boundary

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the half space $\Omega=\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_N)\in\mathbb{R}^N:x_N>0\}$. Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ a positive bounded solution of
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta u+f(x_N,u)=0, & \mbox{in} & \Omega\\
u=0, & \mbox{on} & \partial\Omega
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Here $f:[0,\infty]\times[0,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, for any t-finite interval $f$ is Lipschitz in $u$ on $[0,M]$, $M=\sup_{\Omega}u$, and $(y^{j})_{j}\subset\Omega$ such that $u(y^{j})\rightarrow M$. In $|x|<\delta$, define $u^{j}(x)=u(y^{j}+x)$.

How can I prove by elliptic estimates up to the boundary that there exists a subsequence of the $u^{j}$ such that the $u^{j}$ converge uniformly in $|x|<\delta/2$ to a function $u_{0}$?

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Are $y^j$ supposed to be tangent to $\partial\Omega$? What is assumed at infinity? In case $u(\infty)=0$ is not assumed, is $\{y^j\}$ supposed to be bounded? And what is a t-finite interval?

Comment: Let me answer your questions. By the supremum definition, there exists a sequence $(y^j)_j$ such that $u(y^{j})\rightarrow M$, therefore you have no hypothesis about the behavior of this sequence and you have no hypothesis about the behavior of the solution $u$ at the infinity, you have only a solution of this problem. The "t-finite interval" means that for each subset $[0,t]\subset[0,\infty]$, the function $f$ is Lipschitz in $u$ on $[0,M]$. My doubt can be found in the Lemma $1$ of the paper "Symmetry for elliptic equations in a half space - Berestycki, Caffarelli, Nirenberg".